# Get-ChildItem reports different value to Explorer

Tags: powershell

Fairly straight question, why does `Get-ChildItem -recurse` report a totally different number of folders to what Explorer reports?

For example I have a data drive with a substantial number of folders when you take into account recursion through all subfolders. Explorer reports one figure, Get-ChildItem reports something totally different?

Am I being dense and missing something? Hidden folders etc are not displayed in explorer and `Get-ChildItem` isn't using the `-force` flag so it should show the same result?

Comment: Are you sure that you do not have some files in those folders as well because the command as you listed will report files and folders. You can restrict it to just folders by using the Attributes argument. For example "Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Attributes d".

Comment: I am using the PSIsContainer on the pipeline

Comment: Exactly how are you counting? What numbers do you expect? Have you tried on a smaller test case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whether you're displaying hidden folders has no effect on the folder count you get from Windows Explorer, which will count all the folders whose parent folder you have permissions to list. However, **Get-ChildItem** with the **-Force** parameter won't always give you the same count as Windows Explorer, because **-Force** also counts junction points, and Windows Explorer does not.

Unless I'm overlooking something, this should always give you the same count you get from Windows Explorer:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Force | ?{$_.PSIsContainer -and ($_.Attributes -notmatch 'ReparsePoint')} | Measure
```

Comment: My theory about hidden files was definitely bogus, I will delete my answer.   Your answer is close (+1 from me), but still does not give the exact right results for large directories on my system (off by a few).  Regardless, you can make this much faster by changing it to `Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Force -Attribute Directory+!ReparsePoint`.  As-is you are pipelining every single file and directory and doing a regex check on it, which is quite expensive :)

Comment: @latkin Ah, that's why it wouldn't let me post the comment I was trying to add under your answer. :) In fact, I did try it with **-Attributes**, except I used the attributes *instead* of **-Force**...but got identical results as I did with **-Force** and the **where** filter. I'll add the comment here:

Comment: I think I see the problem. It *does* recurse into the junction points, excluding the junction points themselves, but including their subdirectories (the way you thought Explorer handles hidden folders). I suspect that your `Program Files (x86)` has junction points linking to directories that have subdirectories, whereas mine doesn't. I also tried filtering by attributes, but got the same results as the command in my answer: `Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Attributes D+H+!ReparsePoint,D+!H+!ReparsePoint | Measure`. I think a recursive function would be necessary to get the same count as Explorer.